# Distutils build include C++ library with setup

Tags: python, c++, cmake, distutils

I'm trying to link glfw to my C++ python extension but I can't do it without cmake.

Here is how I did it in cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Test)

add_subdirectory(lib/glfw)

add_executable(Test py_extend.cpp)

target_include_directories(Test PRIVATE 
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE 
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    glfw
)
```

This works fine. This is what I've tried to do in distutils:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from distutils.ccompiler import CCompiler, new_compiler

our_compiler = new_compiler()
our_compiler.add_include_dir("glfw")
our_compiler.add_library("glfw")
our_compiler.add_library_dir("lib/glfw")

module1 = Extension('test',
                    sources = ['py_extend.cpp', 'src/glfw_binder.cpp'],
                    include_dirs=["include/glfw_binder.h"],
                    libraries=["glfw"],
                    library_dirs=["lib/glfw"]
                    )

setup (name = 'python_test',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is a demo package',
       ext_modules = [module1]
       )
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
python3 build.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'test' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iinclude/glfw_binder.h -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c py_extend.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/py_extend.o
cc1plus: warning: include/glfw_binder.h: not a directory
In file included from py_extend.cpp:4:
./include/glfw_binder.h:4:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

How do I properly implement that cmake code into distutils code?

Comment: what problem are you having? Is there an error message? At a guess you need to link to OpenGL

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've updated the question to include the error. Also how do I link it?

Comment: you need to set the include directory for glfw properly, at a guess `our_compiler.add_include_dir("lib/glfw/include")`, depends on your source code layout

Answer (score 0):

I did it by changing to setuptools (I should change to it since distutils will be depricated soon.) and writing it like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('nerveblox_test',
                    sources = ['py_extend.cpp', 'src/nerveblox_VM.cpp'],
                    include_dirs=["include/nerveblox_VM.h", "lib/glfw/include"],
                    libraries=["lib/glfw"],
                    library_dirs=["lib/glfw"],
                     extra_objects=["lib/glfw/include"]
                    )

setup (name = 'Nerveblox_python_test',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is a demo package',
       ext_modules = [module1]
       )
```